# Manhwa about a girl who dies from drowning and comes back years later

Tags: story-identification, manga

I read part of it a while ago but never got to finish it. I don't remember much, but she basically comes back to life, trying to convince her boyfriend that it's her. I remember him not believing her and mistreating her or something. I remember the main color of the cover being red. I think the boyfriend had a lot of money, maybe something related to business. So he thought she only wanted money or something.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Did the girl come back to life in her own body or was she reincarnated as someone else? Also, do you recall what colour was her hair was?

Comment: Seven Years Later - girl seemingly drowns, but actually re-appears seven years into the future. She's unchanged but everyone she knew is older. Neither of her two male friends appear to disbelieve her, nor mistreat her, and I don't think there's any money concern. Also the cover isn't red. I don't think this is it.